# Building custom PHP extension (.so)

Tags: php

I own a high traffic website that does business in the USA and Canada. We have lots of servers but I want to make sure it's 100% available with no latency whatsoever.

I've learned about creating custom extensions (I know a little C) and I want to create custom validation/files (since php extensions runs faster).

I don't want to ask for all new extensions from you guys but I want to know the general idea on how to build it (I am using CentOS).

Example:

One section of our site is the shipping tracking and this require a postal code.

For the USA I have:

```
function check_usa_postal_code($pc) {
  return is_numeric($pc);
}
```

But for Canada, I would like to build in PHP a custom function like:

`check_canada_postal_code($pc)`

This function should return 1 or 0.

Thanks

Comment: The simplest approach is using [SWIG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705443/how-to-mix-up-c-and-php) to build the C interface code. For your function in particular it's totally pointless to do so. Please consider profiling instead of arbitrary optimizations.

Comment: In http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html there are tutorials for all languages, even C# but for PHP. Amazing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend to read this article:

[Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-)

and here's how to compile:

[UNIX: Compiling PHP Extensions](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/compiling_php_extensions.htm)

[Build PHP extensions with SWIG](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-swig/)

(I recommend [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) like mario said)

Read more on Canadian zip codes at [Postal codes in Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada) since not all letters are being used.

Comment: well this is not a 20 lines piece of code, check the second link, it provides a very good example on how to do it

Comment: Beware: The second link is now spam-ware.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try and build an extension in C you should consider compiling your source code using [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) instead. This will be much simpiler and run your code pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider using [Zephir](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/0.12/en/welcome). Its syntax is very similar to PHP. It is specially designed to create PHP extensions and compiles into an extension.

There are even several converters from regular PHP to Zephir. They do not take into account all the peculiarities, so some minor code changes will be needed before compiling. I use [sandrokeil/php-to-zephir](https://github.com/sandrokeil/php-to-zephir).