# Compile PHP library to PHP extension (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu, compilation

### Hi to all.

I've been programing in **PHP** for 3 years. And I wrote some libraries on PHP during this time. So is it possible to *compile* them in the extension for the PHP interpreter?

Maybe someone will give some guidance on this issue, or something else ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building custom PHP extension (.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241892/building-custom-php-extension-so)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this project - https://zephir-lang.com/
Allows creating php extension in php-similar syntax.

Comment: So... There is no easy way?

Comment: It is easy way :)

Comment: But not the easiest.
Oh well. Since there is no suitable option for me, I probably should start to learn C and write extensions on it. Moreover, there is a lot of documentation on this topic :(