# Best method for a PHP script to communicate with an application?

Tags: php, c++

I'm currently writing a c++ application for a linux server which basically handles requests (I haven't coded the part handling the requests yet, as I'm not sure of the best method).

Basically I have a PHP page that when fired (client hits the page) needs to communicate with the above mentioned application.

Now I can't fire off this application each time it's needed, as it's a rather complex application that needs to load data before it can do any processing (so it should just stay loaded forever as a daemon).

How would you suggest I have the PHP page make requests to the application?  Should I just use socket programming with TCP/IP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you visited `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705443/how-to-mix-up-c-and-php`? It might be helpful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course try and use raw sockets, but you don't need to. There are products that help you with what you want.

I suggest you take a look at [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). You can easily define what functions your C++ part offers and convert it into a daemon that waits for your requests from PHP. And of course there's a PHP library which you can use to make these requests.

Comment: Interesting, my concern is that the application i'm creating needs to be started once.  It loads a lot of data, so much that it uses about 8GB of RAM while sitting idle.  Would this still support my app?

Comment: That problem is completely independet of the means of RPC you are using. You'll need 8 GB RAM of course, but that is almost too obvious to answer. It should work on a 64 bit machine, so that's okay.

Comment: I can't get over how amazing Apache Thrift is, seriously.  Thanks so much for this reco!!!

Answer (score 2):

[ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) is another project that can help you building a communication layer between your PHP code and a C++ daemon.

There are bindings for C++, PHP, and many other languages.

Comment: I got downvoted ? I find it kind of rude if no justification is provided, especially since ZeroMQ really is a great project ! Please comment on my answer, I'm always open to debate...

Comment: I saw your entry, i've used ZeroMQ many times, brilliant library, if you know that you are using the same platform you can even bytestream objects instead of serializing them through the ZMQ Sockets. Too bad that you got downvoted from other sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with unix sockets, you might use unix domain sockets too:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/transports.unix.php