# Can a web application be made in C#, C++, Fortran, Pascal, etc

Tags: web-applications, webserver, native

(This is more like a generic high-level question)

I wanted to ask about making a web application (one that uses HTML, Ajax, jquery, and some other components) in a language that is not normally used for making web applications.

For example, is it possible to make a web application in e.g. C++, and if so, how is the C++ code integrated with the rest of the application?

Would it be possible to use a combination of e.g C++ and PHP?

Are there reasons why this would be a good idea (e.g. perhaps for commercially sold application?) or a bad idea (e.g. perhaps for effort required, or performance?)...?

Any pointers to books or online material would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question gone bad...

Comment: C++ web applications [aren't terribly uncommon](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).

Comment: Hope Following thread may help you :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705443/how-to-mix-up-c-and-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use any platform/language for web development, as long as they provide necessary functionality.

A web process includes a few steps:

1. Listen to a port to which client (browser, mostly) sends requests (which is :80 by default)
2. Do something. Access to the DB, talk to somewhere. Enjoy yourself.
3. Send an output back to the client

So, if you can make these kinds of specifications comfortable, then you are good to go with any language/platform.

Or you can build a bridge between a currently used web server (like Apache, Nginx, IIS and such) and your Pascal application. This is what most developers would go.

I am currently using PHP, Java Application through command line, Python through command line all together in a single application. I love the way command line works, simple and fast. And we will add another server with Windows to the application for a Windows-specific function. So... If you have enough ropes, you can tie anything together.

Correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. There are libraries which can ease your life. Try [CppWeb](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppweb) C++ library. It can be a good start: it's simple, free, open source, light-weight and portable. For big/advanced projects try [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/).